# Does every operation need to be a single Command?

Tags: c#, command, command-line-arguments, command-pattern

---

**What I want to know:**

Does every single operation provided on the list in the background paragraph need to be a single command? What do the single commands do?

---

**Background:** 
I need to write a program which gets started from the cmd and performs operations on a string you can enter as argument to the command line. You also need to pass the operations to be performed as CLA. 
For example: myprogram.exe /es "This is the string" /ds /rs .
Es = Enter string, ds = display string, rs=  reverse string. 
It is not necessary to implement Undo/Redo.

---

**Possible Operations are:**

• Enter string

• Display string

• Reverse string

• Upperace all letters

• Lowercase all letters

• Uppercase specific letters

• Lowercase specific letters

• Eliminate consecutive duplicates

• Rotate left

• Rotate right

• Run-length encoding

• Run-length decoding

• Drop every n'th character

• Split by string and take first

• Split by string and take last

---

**What did I do / What is my approach:**

I recognized after some research that the optimal way of implementing this example would be to use the Command Pattern and Chain Of Responsibility. I'm reading the book written by the Gang of Four : Design Patterns. 
But I think I do not understand perfectly the concept. I know, that using Command Pattern there is a: Invoker, Receiver, Command, CommandInterface etc. I know that the Invoker (here my ProgramHandler.cs class) generates the single Commands, equips them with a receiver and an Action. And the single Command calls the receiver to execute the action. The receiver is a class called StringManipulator which holds all the methods to manipulate a string. My idea is also, that the parser parses the CLA and "tells" the ProgramHandler which Commands need to be created.

**(Please have a look on my first design approach, picture at the end!)**

But:

---

**Additional Questions:**

Isn't that quite a bit of an overhead of having an abstract class SimpleCommand which holds the receiver and action and afterwards the concrete commands inherit from SimpleCommand?

It feels a bit wrong, but on the other hand: Each command needs an action and a receiver, so giving each concrete command these fields separately would be against the "rules" of object oriented Programming.

How is this designed correctly?

---

**Class Diagram**

[Class Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PasHu.jpg)

Thank you for your time and help!

Best regards!

Comment: This sounds more like something for the [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Normally a parser can have multiple command on one line but need a separator like a semi-colon between commands.

Comment: @RufusL I don't think so: Questions on Code Review Stack Exchange must contain at least 3 lines of code. So this is not possible.